# Examine logs from the past with logcat?

Tags: android, debugging, logging, stack-trace, android-logcat

I'd like to examine stack traces from the last hours. I haven't found a proper [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat) command. Does Android "forget" those logs?

*First story:*

*When I find an unhandled exception in my co-workers Iphone App, he connects the iphone to his computer and reads the stack trace into x-code. X-Code also visualizes the exception in a nice way.
Is there a smth. similar in Android?*

Comment: Collecting maximum logs with increased logger buffer size - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72300371/4694013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't be able to see those logs from the past hours. Imagine that your phone stores all logs, how much space will it consume in a couple of days?

So, this is what I do:

- I'm in the autobus, and suddenly the app I'm working on crashes!
- I'd like to see what's the logcat output to analyze it at home
- I just launch the [Android log collector app](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/), and send myself an email with the logcat output
- I get home, have dinner, feed the dogs and then I can start working on the logtrace I emailed hours ago.

Comment: Installed. ;) Also will build http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRAHowTo into my app now

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know that app. Thank you so much.