# Access old/past logs from logcat or Android

Tags: android, logcat

Is it possible to get old logs (such as logs of one hour or one day before) of an Android device?

I am asking this because sometimes testers encounter some errors. The Android developer says that the error is related to the device's hardware. To prove his claim, he has to show the error inside the logs. But he says that when attaching an Android device to his computer, he cannot see past logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, but there are libraries like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) which will automatically send you detailed crash reports including the user LogCat if you want (disabled by default).

If you don't want to use a library, when an error occurs you can also write the content of the Logcat to a file that your testers can easily find (like in a log folder of the SD card). It shouldn't be very hard to implement.

Comment: "can also write the content of the Logcat to a file that your testers can easily find" - how can a log be written to the standardout and file as well?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how it was back then, but with current Android versions you can use `adb logcat` to get at older logs. On my device this is limited to the current boot, but I understand that on some devices older logs may be accessible.

`adb logcat --help` will have all the details (note that your device must be connected even for the help functionality), here's an example usage:

To get all the logs from today at 4PM:

```
adb logcat -d -T "2022-01-27 16:00:00.000"
```

Or:

```
adb logcat -d -T "01-27 16:00:00.000"
```

> As Year may not be valid in some ADB versions, with message:
>
> ```
> -T "2022-01-27 16:00:00.000" not in "%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%q" time format
> ```

Comment: Right now with option "T" (in capital) I get `logcat: invalid option -- T Unrecognized Option`. 
The one which is mentioned in logcat is "t". However, it works differently (you specify how recent lines you want to see: `-t <count>      print only the most recent <count> lines (implies -d)`

Comment: Check your ADB version - on version 29, both `-t <count>` and `-t <time>` are valid. Also, both `-t` and `-T` should be valid (both support both limit by lines and limit by time) where the difference is that `-t` dumps and exits while `-T` dump and continues to follow the log.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way you can access the past logs, unless you save them.

Ask your testers to save the Log the moment they see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the logger buffer size option on the developer option, one could choose the logger size for each buffer. There are quite a several logger sizes available and they include `64k, 256k, 1M, 4M, and 16M`. I recommend only increasing the buffer size for debugging purposes, as the logging area is a ring buffer, this helps to capture old logs to some extent once we encounter the glitch that we're looking out for.

[image]