# How to automatically backup all the logs of android studio when a device is connected

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an android application.I am trying to debug my android application on real device.Problem is devices logs are to fast(even I filter it for a single application).So my question is there any tool or  a way so that we can backup automatically all logs of android studio logcat?

Comment: Refer this question, if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428643/examine-logs-from-the-past-with-logcat

Comment: tool mention in this post only shows log of only one minute I want to see all logs of 1 hr before at least